# css shorthand for border

Tags: css, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS 2005 and while editing a css border property,

Visual Studio displays following tooltip

```
border:[border-style][border-width][border-color]|inherit
```

which means following is valid

```
border:solid 2px #000
```

but as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168774/how-to-keep-memorize-all-css-shorthands/2168790#2168790) shorthand cheat sheet

following is valid shorthand

```
border:2px solid #000
```

I googled for "css shorthand border" and browsed 2-3 articles which all point that border:2px solid #000 is valid

in VS2005 css version for validation is 2.1

So I am not sure why VS2005 displays the shorthand in different manner?

Are both approaches correct ?

Comment: Cause visual studio css validation is only good for turning it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C CSS Validator validates both

Answer (score 0):

The specification only specifies width | style | color. However I've never had any issue using the way shown in Visual Studio. I'd say they are both pretty safe.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties